# How to test a whole string of individual characters in a for loop against another string?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, printing

```
rna = input('Enter a rna sequence: ')
for i in rna:
    if i in 'acguACGU':
        print('That is a valid rna sequence.')
    else:
        print('That is not a valid rna sequence.')
```

I want to have the users input be tested against the string, and print the answer only if each letter in the users input is valid or not valid. (EX: an input of GCC should give me one print of ('That is a valid rna sequence') instead of printing 3 times.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` and test if the set of `rna` (user-input) is a subset of your set containing all possible characters (Or the other way round, if the set of all possible characters is a super set of the set of input). Example -

```
rna = input('Enter a rna sequence: ')
seq = set('acguACGU')
if seq.issuperset(rna):
    print('That is a valid rna sequence.')
else:
    print('That is not a valid rna sequence.')
```

Comment: I'm going to have to investigate some more of those set methods, that's a pretty powerful tool I didn't realize was there.

Answer (score 0):

```
rna = input('Enter a rna sequence: ')
if all(c in "acgu" for c in rna.lower()):
    print('That is a valid rna sequence.')
else:
    print('That is not a valid rna sequence.')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rna = input('Enter a rna sequence: ')
for i in rna:
    if i not in 'acguACGU':
        print('That is not a valid rna sequence.')
        break
else:
    print('That is a valid rna sequence.')
```

See - https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops